# When i'm in my viewport, rendering with cycles just looks like eevee

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine

I'm making the donut from the Blender guru tutorial series, but when I went to switch to cycles, it was supposedly already rendering in cycles even though it looked like Eevee. when I was working yesterday, cycles worked fine but as soon as I opened the file again today, I couldn't see it in cycles.

Comment: It sounds like you may be in material preview mode (second to right of the 4 circles in top right of viewport). To get the Cycles look, switch to "Rendered Preview" (farthest circle to the right)

Comment: Hello :). Please add some images to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Go to *Output* properties on the far right panels. From *Post Production* uncheck *Sequencer*.